# Multiple inserts in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a many to many relation between a table product and a table order, the link table is ProductInOrder.
I want to make a stored procedure with a list of product ids as inputs and what it would do is create a new order and add a new record to the link table for each product.

I have now achieved this using a client initiated transaction, then calling a sp to create a new order, then a loop in the client to call a sp to create each record in the link table.
But there must be a way to do this in sql.

Any ideas?

Best

Comment: You are asking how to write a query but it is difficult to answer if we don't know what RDBMS you are using (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, PostGreSQL, SQLite…) and what version of that RDBMS. Their implementation of SQL differ and there are features that we could use to improve the query efficiency for example. Also, SQL syntax can vary.

Comment: @Benoit Also the client here is important too as not all clients can take advantage of all the features of a given  RDBMS

Comment: I am using C# and MSSQL, but I want this as an example, not a real life application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something like this (for MSSQL, at least):

```
declare @Sql varchar(max) = '
insert into ProductInOrder (OrderID, ProductID)
select
    ' + @OrderID + ',
    ProductID
from
    Product
where
    ProductID in (' + @Products + ')'

sp_executesql(@Sql)
```

Pass `@Products` in as a comma-delimited string of integers, e.g.-`'1,2,3,15,100'`.

To load up a temp table in C#, you'd do this (using a `SqlCommand` named `comm`):

```
comm.CommandText = "create table #ProductList (ProductID int)";
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
comm.CommandText = "insert into #ProductList (ProductID) values (@ProductID)";
foreach(int product in products)
{
    comm.Parameters.Clear();
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", product);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
comm.Parameters.Clear();
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", orderId);
comm.CommandText = "insert into ProductInOrder (OrderID, ProductID) " +
    "select @OrderID, p.ProductID from Product p inner join #ProductList pl on " +
         "p.ProductID = pl.ProductID";
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
comm.CommandText = "drop table #ProductList";
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: That is actualy pretty good. There is no way to do that without dynamic SQL?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You can load up a temp table if you'd like and pass that in, but you can't pass an array of values directly. Here are the only data types you can pass in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

Comment: The temp table thing is promising, I will see if I can come up with an example.

Comment: Added a C# example with a temp table for you.

Comment: You can do that thing without dynamic sql, use XML variable and pass that xml variable in the procedure and use there value of xml variable in the procedure read data from this and you can do in one single insert.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option that performs wonderfully and shortens the number of round-trips to the server from your application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Performs very well in the scenarios I have used it in.  Really excellent option.  There are examples out on the web that can be viewed as I am unable to locate my Proof of Concept I implemented for it.  It does require the creation of a table datatype on the database you are targeting.